# how to save and update menu in php laravel

Tags: php, database, menu, dynamic-pages

I want to create an admin panel where I can change almost everything of the pages.
Should we save every menu-item and its children in a different table in the database? 
Doesn't it slow down the speed of loading the page?

Comment: Wy not in same table with rows parent_id and position/order?

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to save menu items in the DB. This means that you have to load these objects during every pageview. However as there should not be too many menu items then it does not take too long and you should be able to load needed menus with one or a few SQL queries.